# Spring MVC - A way to dump unknown parameters of RequestBody into Map<String,String> variable?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have the set up like below.

```java
public class TestController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test")
  public void readQuery(@RequestBody Query query) {
  }
}
```

```java
public class Query {
  private String foo;
  private String bar;
  private Map<String,String> other;
}
```

I'd like to be able to post a json object like:

```
{
  "foo":"1",
  "bar":"2",
  "x":"3",
  "y":"4"
}
```

And have spring automatically populate foo and bar into the query's foo and bar variables, and any undefined parameters into the `other` mapping (so in this case `other` would contain x-->3 and y-->4). Is such a thing configurable? My current temp work around is to replace `@RequestBody Query query` with `@RequestBody Map<String,String> mapping` and iterate over the mapping and read the variables into my Query object. I'd love to be able to get rid of a tedious step like this.

Comment: You can do it rather easily with a custom deserializer plus reflection. I can show you an example if what I said didn't make sense.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I'd love to see an example!

Comment: You are using Jackson, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented earlier, here is an example to do what you want.

Create a custom deserializer:

```
public class QueryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Query> {

    @Override
    public Query deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {

        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator = node.fields();

        Query query = new Query();
        Map<String, String> other = new HashMap<>();

        while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = nodeIterator.next();
            Field field = getField(entry.getKey());

            if (field != null) {
                try {
                    field.set(query, entry.getValue().textValue());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                other.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().textValue());
            }
        }

        if (other.size() != 0) {
            query.setOther(other);
        }

        return query;
    }

    public static Field getField(String entryName) {
        for (Field field : Query.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String fieldName;
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class)) {
                fieldName = field.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value();
            } else {
                fieldName = field.getName();
            }
            if (entryName.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
                return field;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Register the deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = QueryDeserializer.class)
public class Query {
...
}
```

Now when you use it in a controller like below, Spring will automatically use your deserializer to build the object as you want:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String test(@RequestBody Query query) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial mapping won't work. There may be a workaround, but the much easier way would be to introduce a wrapper Object and change your json object:

```
{
 "foo":"1",
 "bar":"2",
 "other":{
   "x":"3",
   "y":"4"
 }
}
```